# Чтение и запись в файл

Tags: файлы, c++

Мне нужно прочитать строки из одного файла и записать их в другой.
Я пытался сделать это следующим образом:

```
ifstream in(input.txt);
ofstream out(output.txt);
string temp
while(!in.eof()){
getline (in,temp,'\n');
out<temp<endl;
}
```

Но в output.txt ничего не записывается. Наверное, потому, что я перед началом записи в output.txt не закрыл input.txt.
Но если закрывать input.txt, то возникают следующие сложности:

1. Если закрывать и открывать input.txt после считывания каждой строчки, то это вероятно будет замедлять программу.
2. А если сначала прочитать весь input.txt например в `vector<string>`, закрыть input.txt, а потом этот вектор записать в output.txt. То если input.txt очень большой (например, 5 гигов), то, насколько я понимаю, оперативной памяти может не хватить, т.е. нужно это как-то проверять.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всё это сделать, как Вы решаете данные проблемы?
Задача, в общем-то, довольно типовая, но вот сейчас задумался над этими нюансами и не знаю, как правильнее сделать...

Comment: Вы дословно (добуквенно) привели текст программы? Если так, то там куча ошибок (((

Comment: По количеству синтаксических ошибок, я заключаю, что это вольный пересказ.

Вы уверены, что файл input.txt не пуст и, что именно output.txt пуст после успешного завершения программы?

Comment: Да у меня сейчас просто нет исходника под рукой и компилятора тоже нет, вот и написал по памяти..

Answer (score 3):

```
ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");
string temp;
while(!in.eof()){
  getline (in,temp,'\n');
  out << temp << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, значит я просто где то ошибся. Просто у меня чего то в output.txt не записывалось вот я и решил что дело в том что я input.txt не закрыл и в общем запутался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(in >> s){
out << s;
}
in.close();
out.close();
//лично я делал так, когда переписывал утилиту cat -- все вроде работает.
```